# libopencv_java342.dll: Can't find dependent libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, opencv-contrib

I am trying to run a face recognition project which uses opencv and its contrib function. 
I have imported the opencv_342.jar as user libraries. and give the native library location to the folder where all the dll files are.
It is still program giving error of

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\opencv_build\bin\libopencv_java342.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.demo.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:9)
```

I don't know why It is unable to find other libraries which dll files are in bin folder